# EWS: How to upload attachment first before sending an email?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

I use Exchange Web Service API to do sending email. It is very easy to add attachments by just writing

```
message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(attachmentname);
```

The problem is attaching process happens in sending process. I found that yahoo, gmail and hotmail they all uploading attachmetns first before you sending the mail. How to do so?

Answer (score 1):

It's the EWS Managed API which does this uploading and sending in one process. But in the background, multiple requests are made to the Exchange server:

1. Create the message in the Drafts folder of your mailbox
2. Upload the attachments
3. Send the items.

If you want to, you can do this yourself. But I don't see the point in doing that. What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, GMail for example does not use the same manner of attachment. For instance, when you attach something, I am guessing the files get uploaded to some server and then they just provide you with a Link for the download. So I think you can upload the file to some server (be it FTP, or just a database) and then just add the links to the download of the files in the body of the email.

Good luck. I will be looking into the thread to see if there is in fact a way to do this.

Hanlet

Comment: Upload attachment to a server? Bind attachment and message with itemid?

Comment: Exactly. I noticed that's how GMail does it. They also Zip all of the files if there are more than one, I am guessing this all happens within Google servers, instead of the SMTP server.